# Rounding a Bill Total in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to provide app users with the number of tip they would have to leave so that their bill would be rounded to a nice number. Example:

Let's say the bill is 5.21 tipping @ 20 percent = 1.04 tip.

5.21 + 1.04 = 6.25 total. To make the tip 7.00 they would have to tip 1.79.

I thought my logic was good here but I'm showing weird numbers popping when I run it. No errors in logcat, so it is something in my code. I'm pretty sure it is somewhere in the rounding part of the code as I'm not sure if I'm doing it even correctly at this point.

The code is:

```
package mkelleyjr.example.tippycalc;



import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText amt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill_amt);
    final EditText tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bill_percent);
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);
    final TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
    final TextView round = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.round);


    Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                     DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
                     decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);


                 try{

                    double amount = Double.parseDouble(amt.getText().toString());
                    double tip_per = Double.parseDouble(tip.getText().toString());
                    double tip_cal = (amount * tip_per) / 100;

                    double totalcost = amount + tip_cal;

                    decimalFormat.format(totalcost);

                    // round totalcost then perform math on it

                    double rounded = (double)Math.round(totalcost);

                    double roundtotal = rounded - totalcost;


                    result.setText("Tip Amount : " + " $ " + Double.toString(tip_cal));
                    total.setText("Total Cost: "  + " $ " + totalcost);
                    round.setText("Tip:" + roundtotal + " to round bill");



                 }catch (NumberFormatException e) {


                 }

                    }
                });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Thank you for any advice or feedback you can give.

Comment: So, my understanding would be, you want to round the value UP to the nearest round dollar amount

Comment: Using doubles for currency = fail.

Comment: That "duplicate" is merely a comment and doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: No, that duplicate actually provides the answer to the question.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not the duplicate answers your question, your question itself has problems.  You have not explained what _"I'm showing weird numbers popping"_ means, WITH EXAMPLES OF WHAT YOU ARE SEEING and how this differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing `result.setText("Tip Amount : " + " $ " + Double.toString(tip_cal));`, I'm guessing you're getting a lot of nines in your output. Doubles can't store cents exactly, so the math will be off, but if you're not a financial institution and just dealing with < $10,000 transactions, do

`result.setText(String.format("Tip Amount :$%.2f", tip_cal));`

One more thing: `decimalFormat.format(totalcost);` is at best a no op, at worst a thread safety issue. It doesn't *change* the totalcost, it returns a StringBuffer (that shows you just how old it is).

Answer (score 0):

You really want to be using BigDecimal here, rather than Double. As @David mentioned, "Doubles can't store cents exactly". BigDecimal type can. BigDecimal gives you precise control over precision, and rounding.

It's a much slower data type than Doubles, but for financial applications, it is far, far better.

Granted, a simple tip calculator is not High Finance, but the basic tenet still applies. When operating on things such as dollar values, BigDecimal is a much better data type.

Answer (score 0):

Two things jump out at me....

First `Math.round` can round DOWN, so a value of 5.22 would be rounded down to `6`, instead of up to `7`

Now you can use `(int)totalcost + 1` which basically trims off the decimal elements or `Math.ceil(totalcost)` depending on your needs.

The second is you don't seem to understand how formatter are using

```
decimalFormat.format(totalcost);
```

Won't do anything, numbers are free from formatting information.  Instead, you use a formatter to return a representation of the value in the specified format...

With all that tucked under our belts, something like...

```
String tipFormat = decimalFormat.format((tip_cal)

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

try {

    double amount = Double.parseDouble("5.21");
    double tip_per = Double.parseDouble("20");
    double tip_cal = (amount * tip_per) / 100;

    double totalcost = amount + tip_cal;

    double rounded = (int)totalcost + 1;

    double roundtotal = rounded - totalcost;

    System.out.println("Tip Amount : " + decimalFormat.format((tip_cal)));
    System.out.println("Total Cost: " + decimalFormat.format(totalcost));
    System.out.println("Tip: " + decimalFormat.format(roundtotal) + " to round bill");
    System.out.println("Bill Tally: " + decimalFormat.format(totalcost + roundtotal));

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Will output...

```
Tip Amount : $1.04
Total Cost: $6.25
Tip: $0.75 to round bill
Bill Tally: $7.00
```

Having said all that, `double` and `float` are not well suited for monetary calculations.  You can use `long` or `BigDecimal` as alternatives, for example...

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

try {

    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble("5.21"));
    BigDecimal tip_per = new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble("20"));

    BigDecimal tip_cal = amount.multiply(tip_per).divide(new BigDecimal(100));
    BigDecimal totalcost = amount.add(tip_cal);

    BigDecimal rounded = totalcost.setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING);
    BigDecimal roundtotal = rounded.subtract(totalcost);

    System.out.println("Tip Amount : " + nf.format((tip_cal)));
    System.out.println("Total Cost: " + nf.format(totalcost));
    System.out.println("Tip: " + nf.format(roundtotal) + " to round bill");
    System.out.println("Bill Tally: " + nf.format(totalcost.add(roundtotal)));

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This example uses the `NumberFormat` class instead of creating it's own formatter based on the `DecimalFormat`, not sure if this is available in Android or not, but you should consider using it (or the equivalent) as it takes into account the users local

Comment: Yeah, it was a great learning experience for me to ;)